# Radius server test tool

Tags: radius

Is there any good tool to test Radius server? (linux|windows|unix)
Authorisation check is a minimum requirement.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, install the linux freeradius tools, including radtest.

Comment: remember that the radtest is just an interface to the radclient tool

Answer (score 1):

You can download from: 
http://www.aradial.com/DownLoads/AccessPointSimulator.zip